# noo puedo declarar la variable global

Tags: c

si quiero declarar estas variables globales

```
int D1=2;
int D2 = D1-2;

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
}
```

porque me manda un error el compilador aqui int D2 = D1-2; ?
dice initializer const is not constant

Comment: He editado mi respuesta. Aunque *casi* deberia ser otra pregunta ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes declararla perfectamente.

Lo que **no** puedes hacer es **inicializarla** con el valor de otra variable.

Las variables globales solo se pueden inicializar con valores constantes. `D1 = 2` es correcto. `D2 = D1 - 2` es *incorrecto*, puesto que haces referencia a *otra* variable.

Para esos casos, se suelen emplear *macros* del preprocesador:

```
#define VALOR_CONSTANTE 2

int D1 = VALOR_CONSTANTE;
int D2 = VALOR_CONSTANTE - 2;
```

Las *macros* **no son código** C; su *procesado* se realizar **antes** de que el compilador empiece su trabajo. Por ello, cuando el compilador *ve* el código, lo que realmente ve es:

```
int D1 = 2;
int D2 = 2 - 2;
```

Ahí, no hay ninguna referencia a otras variables, y se compila sin problemas.

**EDITO**

El modificador `const`, aplicador a la *declaración de variables*, se usa para *impedir* que cambiemos el valor de una variable, después de inicializarla:

```
const int a = 10;

int main( void ) {
  a = 20; // <- ERROR !!
  ...
```

Es una *ayuda* para el programador, pero `a` **sigue** siendo una variable, **no** un **valor constante**.

```
const int a = 10;
int b = a - 5; // <- ERROR. a es una variable, no una expresión constante.
```

Comment: Gracias master me quedo claro

Answer (score 2):

Para declarar globales en C y utilizarla de la forma que estás mostrando (utilizando valores constantes en su declaración) vas a necesitar la cláusula `define`, acá te dejo un ejemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define D1 5 // No requiere definir el tipo
int D2 = D1 - 2; // Requiere especificar el tipo

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    printf("Valor de D2: %d\n", D2);
    return 0;
}
```

Para este caso debes utilizar `define` que es un sentencia del preprocesador, es decir, que su valor se asigna a la variable D1 como primer paso al momento de compilar el programa completo, de la forma en que los estabas haciendo antes, al asignar el valor de D2 el compilador tiraba error porque no podía obtener el valor de D1 ya que este no estaba **definido** en ese momento.

Espero haberte ayudado, saludos!

Comment: El `const` **no** es necesario. Su uso no tiene nada que ver con usar o no *macros* del procesador.

Comment: @Trauma el const para que caso lo ocupo ? o sea en que varia si le pongo const antes ?, se supone que una variable const no puede modificar su valor a lo largo del programa ejemplo si en el main digo const int x =5; la x siempre sera 5 o me equivoco? , en caso de ser asi eso tmb corre para la variable global ? tampoco se podra modificar despues ?

Comment: Perdón! Las hice constantes, cuando el autor solo preguntaba por globales, ahí edito